# Читает только текст написанный на русском

Tags: java, netty

```
public void start() {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                .group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ClientAdapterInitializer());

        Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
        System.out.println("Клиент запущен.");
        System.out.println("Ожидание ввода данных...");

        String scanner = new Scanner(System.in).next();

        channel.writeAndFlush(scanner);


        System.out.println("Сообщение отправлено.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Вот код. Проблема в том что если ввести в консоль данные типа 
Тест123 - он отправит это серверу.
Test123 - на сервер не придет оповещение о том пришло ли это сообщение. (Тут слово тест123 написано на английском.)
123 - на сервер не придет сообщение (тут просто цифры).

С чем это связано?? 
Почему  он воспринимает только русский текст?
Как решить такую проблему?

Содержимое класса ClientAdapterInitializer.

```
public class ClientAdapterInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ClientHandler());
    }
}
```

Только учусь работать с netty.
Дайте Полезных советов.

upd:

Класс ClientHandler

```
public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, String s) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Сообщение: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
        System.out.println("Сообщение: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ещё код `ClientHandler`.

Comment: Пробуйте изменить вызов с writeAndFlush(string) на write(string); flush();. Так же конвертируйте строку в массив байтов